# Laravel Upload files(image) to Firebase Storage

Tags: file, laravel-5, firebase-storage

I am working on my android app with Laravel backend on the admin side, but I am stuck on how to upload files to the storage of firebase...Help please.

Comment: Did you google something ? like this https://www.cloudways.com/blog/firebase-realtime-database-laravel/

Comment: yes i did, this is about Database (datas only) but me I want to upload files itself like photos, pdf files and so on...upload files to storage and use the download link in Realtime Firebase

Comment: @user5458938 did you manage to get this working?